# VueJS Evento com Mixins

Tags: vue.js

Estou a testar Mixins no VueJS e me surgiu uma dúvida.
Tem como eu chamar um evento diretamente de um Mixins sem eu ter que atribuir no meu `methods` ?

**MyMixins.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        Alerta(){
            alert('WORK!')
        }
    }
})
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
   <button v-on:click="AlertaInterno">test</button>
</template>
<script>
   export default{
         methods:{
            AlertaInterno(){
            this.Alerta()
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

> O código acima funciona. Eu queria saber como eu poderia invocar a função do mixin diretamente, algo assim:

**app.vue**

```
<template>
   <button v-on:click="this.Alerta()">test</button>
</template>
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esta registrando um *Mixin Global*, basta apenas referenciar o método no evento `click` sem há necessidade de criar novo método.

```
<button v-on:click="Alerta">test</button>
```

Mas a [documentação](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Registrando-Mixin-Global) deixa um alerta.

> Utilize mixins globais raramente e cuidadosamente, porque eles afetam cada uma das instâncias Vue criadas, incluindo os componentes de terceiros. Na maioria dos casos, você deveria utilizá-los somente para tratar opções personalizadas, como demonstrado no exemplo acima. É também uma boa ideia disponibilizá-los como [Plugins](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Escrevendo-um-Plugin), para evitar uso duplicado.

Vamos cria um [plugin](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Escrevendo-um-Plugin) básico, ele deve conter um método `install` e será chamado tendo o construtor `Vue` como primeiro argumento e outras opções.

```
const Alerta = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.mixin({
      methods: {
        AlertaA() {
          alert("Alerta A!");
        },
        AlertaB() {
          alert("Alerta B!");
        },
        AlertaC() {
          alert("Alerta C!");
        }
      }
    });
  }
};

export default Alerta;
```

Para utilizar

```
import Vue from "vue";
...
// Plugin
import Alerta from "./alerta.mixins";
Vue.use(Alerta);
```

O template:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button v-on:click="AlertaA">A</button>
    <button v-on:click="AlertaB">B</button>
    <button v-on:click="AlertaC">C</button>
    <button v-on:click="AlertaD">D</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

> Podes ver funcionando em [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2wmp0xlq6p?view=preview)

Comment: Perfeito!! Obrigado!!!